# How to find Mean and Variance on Normal Distribution (Marks on subject)

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have surveyed 100 students to ask what is their mark/grade on Mathematics.
After that our teacher told us to create a normal distribution out of it. My question is how can I find the mean and the variance, standard deviation? thanks.
(Im so bad in math, hope someone can help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exercise of yours is basically the *fitting of normal distribution*. For this, we first calculate the mean $\mu$ and S.D $\sigma$ from the given data. Then the normal probability curve to be fitted to the given data is given by: $$y=f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}\,\,, -\infty < x < \infty$$

The process for finding the mean and S.D may be termed as same to the process of [finding them for **grouped data**](http://www.milan.k12.mo.us/vimages/shared/vnews/stories/549185c9bbf95/ch03sec3.ppt).

Comment: for mean ill add all the grades and divide it to 100? like an average?

Comment: @AlexanderCruz See the link I have provided. They have an example as well.

Comment: i didnt notice the link. thanks! :D